# Cannot upload multiple files

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a small part of my app that allow users to upload 5 different images and as soon as an image has been uploaded it show a small thumbnail of it.

Since I upload a single image everything works fine.

As soon as I try to upload multiple image, let's sat 3 all together, it end up to upload 3 equal images showing 3 equal thumbnails... And I'm getting crazy.

Here is the code that handle this part:

HTML:

```
<input id="pics" type="file" accept="image/*" class="upload" data-imageid="" data-imageurl="" data-callback="displayPics" data-image-type="pics" multiple />
```

JS:

```
const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');

[].slice.call(fileInputs).forEach(fileInput => {
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
        uploadFile(
            fileInput,
            fileInput.getAttribute('data-callback')
        );
    });
});

unction uploadFile(input, callback) {
    let formData = new FormData();

    Object.keys(input.files).forEach(current => {
        formData.append('file', input.files[current]);
        fetchAPI({
            target: 'pics/',
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (callback !== undefined) {
                window[callback](data.response);
            }
        }, err => {
            // err...
        });
    });
}
```

Can I know what is wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`fetch()` call does not have a URL set. `"target"` is not a valid options property of object passed to `fetch()`.

You also do not call `Response.json()` to get a JavaScript object representation of `Response`.

The code at Question makes a request for each `File` object instead of a single request.

```
function uploadFile(input, callback) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    for (let file of input.files) {
      // or set property to `file[N]`
      // "file["+ Array.from(formData.keys()).length +"]"
      formData.append("file", file)
    }
    fetchAPI('pics/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (callback !== undefined) {
        window[callback](data.response);
      }
     }, err => {
            // err...
     })
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Well, that `fetchAPI` is something built in and it works fine as it is... I updated the logic behind following your hints and I have 2 issues: `response.json() is not a function` and it upload only a single image. What I return from `data` is only one image. and it run once.

Comment: `formData` is basically an empty object.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo How did you determine that `formData` is an empty object? You should probably set each key at `FormData` instance to a different value

Comment: Just looking into it. Server receive just a single image. The last one added in the multiple field.

Comment: Can you include server code at Question? Have you tried commented code at Answer?